# How to post a story to user's timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am creating FB App that upload and post images, but I ran into a problem. I succeeded to take user's image and to upload it, and to create story about this, but story only appears in news feed, and not on user's timeline. Also, user's friends can see that story on their news feed on main page. I am using Open Graph, and custom object and action (`create` and `photo`). This is code from app:

```
FB.api('/me/appname:create?access_token='+access_token, 'post', {photo: object_id}, function(response) {
                if (!response) {
                    alert('Error occurred.');
                } else if (response.error) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + response.error.message);
                } else {
                    console.log(
                        '<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/me/activity/' + response.id + '\">' +
                        'Story created.  ID is ' + response.id + '</a>');
                }
            });
```

How can I make a story to show up on user's timeline? I read a lot of documentation, but couldn't find a solution to this.

Thanks,
Nikola

Answer (score 0):

When you add action types on your Open Graph configuration's section you will find a list of `capabilities` you must check the last item on the list: `Explicitly Share - This action can specify the user explictly...` then you need to check your story with the [API Graphic Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/) only for test purposes. Make a `POST` in there and the story will be publish in your timeline. Of course you need to have a correct meta tags in your page. Copy and paste your link with the meta tags [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to be sure everything is doing correctly